# Is there a quick way to shift to a fork in github?

Tags: github

The following happens to me from time to time:

1. clone something from github
2. discover something I want to fix.
3. want to offer it back.
4. Go make a fork
5. clone my fork
6. manually merge my changes to the fork
7. open a pull request

Somehow, it seems to me that there should be a simpler way to get from 'I've got local changes in a local branch' to 'I've got changes in a fork I can submit a pull for.'

Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github has the [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) gem for maniplating their API.

Secondarily ( and I think what you're looking for) you can add a second remote to your original repo like

```
git remote add myfork git://github.com/defunkt/hub.git # for the case of hub
```

and then

```
git push -u myfork branchname
```

to push branchname up to your fork from the original repo. The `-u` flag sets that branches upstream to be your fork.